# Replace instances of certain tags in a text string using PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

If I have a text string like this:

```
In the beginning<WH7225> God<WH430> created<WH1254><WH853> the heaven<WH8064> and<WH853> the earth<WH776>.
```

And I want to replace the tags <> with a link containing the H and the following number, how can I do this with PHP?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: there could be other tags in some pices of text, so the keyword is WH. this is the identifier that seperates it from others. some tags are like this <WG1234>

Comment: @anubhava I would like to achive this:
<a href="mysite.php?code="WH7225">WH7225</a>
With the unike number for every tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$s = 'In the beginning<WH7225> God<WH430> created<WH1254><WH853> the heaven<WH8064> and<WH853> the earth<WH776>.';

$s = preg_replace('~<(WH\d+)>~', '<a href="mysite.php?code=$1">$1</a>', $s);
```

**OUTPUT:**

> `In the beginning<a href="mysite.php?code=WH7225">WH7225</a> God<a href="mysite.php?code=WH430">WH430</a> created<a href="mysite.php?code=WH1254">WH1254</a><a href="mysite.php?code=WH853">WH853</a> the heaven<a href="mysite.php?code=WH8064">WH8064</a> and<a href="mysite.php?code=WH853">WH853</a> the earth<a href="mysite.php?code=WH776">WH776</a>.`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and put parentheses around the `H[0-9]+` (which stands for "the letter H followed by 1 or more numbers) in your search regex (like this: `<W(H[0-9]+)>`) and then use indexes to refer to that in your replace text (like this: `$1` would refer to the first parentheses).

Answer (score 0):

For this example:

```
$string = preg_replace('/<(WH[^>]+)>/', '<a href="mysite.php?code=$1">$1</a>', $string);
```